# regexp extract in google data studio

Tags: regex, extract, looker-studio, re2

I want to create a calculated field in google data studio which only returns the numbers at the beginning of a string which could look like this:

```
123-something-something1
or
32-something-something2
or
1234-somthing-something3
```

I thought that I had the right regex but it's only returning null which means the regex is wrong.

The regex's i've tried:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '.*')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '^[0-9].[0-9]*')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '[0-9].[0-9]*')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '^[0-9]*')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '[0-9]*')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '^[0-9].[0-9]*')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '[0-9].[0-9]*')
```

- `^` this should stand for the beginning of the value
- `[0-9]` should count any number
- `.` should match any character
- `*` counts as an multiplier for the previous character

Really hope someone can help me out since I can't get it to work

Comment: Try `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '^([0-9]+)')` or `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '^([0-9]+).*')`

Comment: Can you add the first regex as an answer. That fixed it for me. So the + sign is like the *?

Comment: The point is to match and *capture* the digits in the beginning of the string. There must be 1) at least 1 digit and 2) the capturing group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is to match and *capture* the digits in the beginning of the string. There must be 1) at least 1 digit and 2) the capturing group.

You may extract the leading digits using

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campagne, '^([0-9]+)')
```

The pattern matches:

- `^`  - start of a string
- `([0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1 (what you extract): one or more  (`+`) digits (`[0-9]`).